# Could the West coast of the United States ever have a greater population than the East coast?

Tags: near-future, futurology, population

The population estimate from 2016 of the US Census Bureau for the West Coast (California, Oregon, Washington) is approximately [39+4+7 = 50 million](https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/table/PST045215/41,53,06,00). The population estimate from 2016 for the [East Coast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Coast_of_the_United_States) (Maine, New Hampshire, Massachusetts, Rhode Island, Connecticut, New York, New Jersey, Pennsylvania, Delaware, Maryland, District of Columbia, Virginia, North Carolina, South Carolina, Georgia, Florida) is approximately 1+1+6+1+3+20+9+12+1+6+1+8+10+5+10+20 = 114 million people ([same source](https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/table/PST045216/00)).

Historically, the level of agricultural technology and associated infrastructure required to sustain massive populations arrived later to the West Coast of the United States than the East Coast, so one might explain part of the disparity in population size as being a historical artifact which will decrease over time. Indeed, the center of population [has historically been drifting westwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_population#United_States).

How far can we expect this trend, of the relative proportion of the population living on the West Coast versus the East Coast to increase, to continue into the future?

**Question:** Are there fundamental demographic constraints imposed by the ecology, climate, and geography of the two regions which prevent one, at "maximum capacity", from having a larger population than the other? Why is one more heavily populated than the other in the present, and can we realistically expect this reason to continue to hold in the future?

The climate of the West Coast [is primarily oceanic and mediterranean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Coast_of_the_United_States#Climate). The climate of the East Coast is primarily [continental, temperate, and humid subtropical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Coast_of_the_United_States#Climate_and_physical_geography). Do these climates limit the number of people that can settle and live there?

For example, Australia has a similar size as the continental United States, but a much smaller population, since most of the landmass is desert which is impossible (with current technology) to densely populate.

As another example, the state of California alone has more land area than Japan, but only about a third of the population of Japan (whose population in turn is greater than that of the present East Coast of the United States). Is this a historical accident, or is Japan's land intrinsically capable of supporting more people than either American coast?

**Attempt:** Italy, like California, mostly has a mediterranean climate, and has been settled continuously for a long time and appears to have a stabilizing/decreasing population, so makes for a good estimate of a "maximally" settled mediterranean climate area. [Its population density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Italy) is approximately 200 inhabitants per square kilometer. Meanwhile, the current [population density of California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_population_density) is approximately 100 inhabitants per square kilometer, with a population of approximately 40 million, so assuming it becomes approximately "maximally" settled in the future, like in Italy, we can assume a "maximum" population of 80 million people for California alone.

France has also been continuously settled for a long period of time and has well-developed technology, so we can use it as a model for a "maximally settled" oceanic climate (since most of France is oceanic). [Its population density](http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/france-population/) is approximately 120 people per square kilometer. Meanwhile, the [current population density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_population_density) of Washington is approximately 40 people per square kilometer, so we can approximately triple its population to get its "maximally settled" population of 21 million. Meanwhile the population density of Oregon is approximately 15 people per square kilometer, so we can multiply its current population by 8 to get an approximate figure for its "maximally settled" population of 24 million.

So, in total, using population settlement patterns of countries with similar climates in Europe as a model, we can approximate the "maximally settled" population of the West Coast as 80+21+24 = 125 million people.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59051/discussion-on-question-by-chill2macht-could-the-west-coast-of-the-united-states).

Comment: Just nuke the East Coast. Easy.

Answer (score 1):

California has a *lot* of mountains and desert, AZ and NV are *all* desert.

The desert can be tamed with enough cheap energy to desalinate ocean water and pipe it where desired, but the mountains really mitigate against high populations.

Comment: Arizona and Nevada aren't part of the West coast. Also the East Coast has the Appalachians.

Comment: Also, 73% of Japan is mountainous, it has less land than California (and even less than the entire West Coast), and yet supports a population three times the size. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Japan#Composition_and_topography Not to mention that your answer does not explain why Oregon and Washington are so sparsely populated despite having less extreme climates than the East Coast. Is this a historical accident which will rectify itself in time, all other things being equal?

Comment: @Chill2Macht good points.  Do Americans like to live like ants, though?  (Some are forced to, in big NYC public housing complexes, but most of the rest of the country seems to prefer suburban sprawl.)

Comment: @Chill2Macht It does not seem fair (or consistent) to exclude Las Vegas and Phoenix and Tucson...which are roughly the same distance from the ocean as the included Pittsburgh and Buffalo and Charlotte.

Comment: @Chill2Macht: Oregon & Washington east of the Cascades are sparsely populated because they're mostly desert.

Comment: @jamesqf and not the warm, pleasant kind of desert in SoCal either, I think.

Comment: @RonJohn: You think the Southern California desert is warm & pleasant?  Can I ask which alien planet you're from, and where you hid your spaceship?

Comment: @jamesqf it's warm and pleasant enough to make 24M people move there.

Comment: @RonJohn: When did 24 million people move to the Southern California DESERT?  Almost all of the population lives in the narrow strip between the ocean and coastal mountains - San Diego to Santa Barbara, basically.  And I can tell you from my own experience of being stationed at Pendleton, it can get pretty darned cold there.

Comment: @jamesqf hmm, I **thought** it was a desert, but maybe not.  https://www.kcet.org/socal-focus/los-angeles-is-not-a-desert-stop-calling-it-one  It's close, though.

Comment: @RonJohn: Not really.  If you've ever spent time there, especially in the few non-urbanized areas left, you'll know that there are major differences between the coastal strip and the true desert east of the mountains.